# How to call a stored procedure in asp classic?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, asp-classic

In my asp code I want to call a stored procedure. This is the code that I have that is working:

```
newHireSQL = "EXEC sp_selectNewHireSQL"
Set rsGetHireID = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsGetHireID.Open newHireSQL,ConnectionString,adOpenStatic
```

However I don't want to write it like that. I want to use this code:

```
Dim Conn
SET rsGetHireID = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
SET Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Conn.CommandText = "sp_selectNewHireSQL"
Conn.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
Conn.ActiveConnection = ConnectionString
Set rsGetHireID = Conn.Execute
```

But for this code, I get a record set that has a record count of `-1`.

Does anyone know why this could be happening and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: (1) [stop using the sp_ prefix](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It doesn't mean what you think it means. (2) add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` to the beginning of the stored procedure.

Comment: If I add `SET NOCOUNT ON;`, then the working code gets a -1 record count, and the non working code still gets a -1 record count.

Comment: http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/why-does-recordcount-return-as-1.html

Comment: Also, why don't you want to write it the way that works?

Comment: Isn't it a bad practice to do it like that, or isn't it more inefficient?

Comment: Did you test them and compare them, or is that just your perception / opinion? You're using classic ASP. Surely you don't expect to run performance circles around other more modern technologies anyway?

Comment: I didn't test it, its just my perception, but am I right?

Comment: You should test it. If you see a performance difference, maybe you are right for your specific case. I suspect you won't find a difference worthy of being worried about - focus on functionality first, *then* worry about performance *when* it is an actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the -1 issue give proper cursor:

```
SET rsGetHireID = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
SET oCommand = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
oCommand.CommandText = "sp_selectNewHireSQL"
oCommand.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
oCommand.ActiveConnection = ConnectionString
rsGetHireID.CursorLocation = 3 'adUseClient
rsGetHireID.Open oCommand
```